# Undefined method `sanitize' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know how sanitize in rails work. I got an error when putting `sanitize(params[:url])` in `update_attribute`.

```
undefined method `sanitize'
```

code:

```
@sample.update_attribute(:url, sanitize(params[:url]))
```

Answer (score 5):

you should use:

```
@sample.update_attribute(:url, ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:url]))
```

Alternatively, you can shorten this by adding something like this in your initializer:

```
class String
  def sanitize
    ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self)
  end
end
```

and then:

```
params[:url].sanitize
```

[reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize#535-sanitize-method-not-functioning-in-controllers-models-or-libs)

Comment: Is it better to use sanitize or I should use strong params?